# Moving inside Ohrid, Macedonia

Tags: public-transport, car-rentals, tips-and-tricks, walking, macedonia

I am planning to travel to Ohrid, Macedonia for 1 or 2 weeks in September. I will stay near the center of Ohrid.

I know that there are a lot of points of views, churchs, monuments to see but what is the best way to move inside the town ? Is everything reachable by walk ? Is it necessary to take the bus ? Should I rent a car/scooter ?

By foot seems to be the most common but I am afraid to miss some important thing because they are too far.

Perhaps, there is also a way to rent a boat to ride along the coast. I didn't find any boat/jetski rental on internet

Comment: Hi and welcome to [travel.se]. [We don't really do recommendations here on Travel.SE.](/help) Moreover, "best" is a subjective term: what might be best for you might not be best for me. Hence why I am voting to close as opinion-based. Please take the site [tour] and read our [help] to gain a better understanding on how this site works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any local buses to transport you within the centre (though there are minibuses from the centre to the main bus station, among others), so walking is the only realistic option besides renting a car. To be honest though, a car won't be necessary - to get to Sveti Naum, for example, there are regional buses as well as a daily boat for 600 Denars (10 euros), and the rest is all within walking distance

Comment: I really though that the car would be useful, thanks. What about going to Skopje ?

Comment: @Weedoze Lots of city buses there, even to the remote Millenium cross (line 25 to Sredno Vodno, then up to the top on a gondola lift). So you're good

Comment: Thank you ! Beyond the question asked, I would love to hear some tips and thing to do.

Comment: @Weedoze You should take a walk along the Vardar River after dark, as well as hanging at the central square called Ploshtad Makedonija. Absolutely gorgeous. During daylight, the fortress and the Millenium cross definitely ought to be visited